# converting c struct to c# from dll

Tags: c#, c, dll, import, struct

I am using a dll that was written in c.  I have imported all the functions i need into my c# program.  Most of the functions i can get to work properly but am having trouble with a few. The functions i am having issues with require a struct as input.  I assume i need to define this struct in C#, which i have done but I am starting to confuse myself so I will leave what i have attempted out.  The struct is fairly long so i will simply what it looks like in c:

```
typedef struct chain_link_info
{
  unsigned short command;
  unsigned long* buff_id;
  FLAGS_TYPES    flags;  // this is a union that i will list below
} CHAIN_LINK_INFO;

typedef union flags_type
{
  unsigned long ulong;

  struct
  {
    unsigned short std_flags;
    unsigned short high
  } ushort;

  struct
  {
    unsigned int a : 1;
    unsinged int b : 1;
    unsinged int c : 1;
    unsinged int d : 1;
    unsinged int e : 2;
    unsinged int f : 1;
    unsinged int g : 1;
    unsinged int h : 1;
    unsinged int i : 1;
    unsinged int j : 1;
    unsinged int k : 1;
    unsinged int l : 1;
    unsinged int m : 1;
    unsinged int n : 1;
    unsinged int o : 1;
    unsigned int high_word :16
  } std_bits;
} FLAGS_TYPE;
```

what is the proper way to define these stucts in C#?  Thank you

Comment: I believe this is a case where [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) comes in to play, but can't be positive.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I removed it.  Must have clicked it by accident.  I'm curious how the union is supposed to be mapped.

Answer (score 1):

Create a C# struct, apply [StructLayout] to it, and list the fields in the same order as in C. For the FLAGS_TYPE structure, you have to use the [FieldOffset] attribute on the fields. All members of a union start at the same memory address, so apply the same [FieldOffset(0)] to them.

UPDATE: now that it's formatted, I think you don't need to use unions at all. Use a single 32 bit integer, and get the different fields with bitwise operations, it's safer that way.

Comment: Yeah, the question should be "What is the correct way to define the structure in C?"  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The C declaration isn't valid, makes it hard to give a good answer.  You cannot normally deal with bit fields but in this special case it works since they're all a multiple of 8 bits.  You need [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] and use [FieldOffset(x)] for each field.  The badly named unsigned long, std_flags and a are at offset 0.  b at 1.  high and high_word at 2.

Comment: my apologizes i have corrected the question to be a bit more like the actual structs.  The original struts are fairly large so i am just trying to trim them down, in hopes that a simple answer will help me see what i am doing wrong.  thank you.

Comment: Well, the bit fields are no longer happy multiples of 8.  You'll have to use the & and | operators if you want to get/set individual bits.

Answer (score 0):

`FieldOffset` is byte unit. 
So, You can express upto byte only through `FieldOffset`.
You may create your own `FieldOffset`.